# Removing list of objects from repository with Spring Data usage

Tags: java, junit, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I want to create a method which will be removing `VerificationToken` objects from database which are older than 30 minutes. 
`VerificationToken.class` looks like:

```
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
class VerificationToken extends AbstractBaseEntity {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @Column(unique = true)
  private String value;

  @Column(unique = true)
  private String email;

  @CreatedDate private LocalDateTime created;

  VerificationToken() {}

  VerificationToken(String value, String email) {
    this.value = value;
    this.email = email;
  }

  public Long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  String getValue() {
    return value;
  }

  public String getEmail() {
    return email;
  }

  LocalDateTime getCreated() {
    return created;
  }
}
```

I am using Spring Data JPA repository like:

```
interface VerificationTokenRepository extends JpaRepository<VerificationToken, Long> {
  void deleteAllByCreatedLessThan(LocalDateTime localDateTime);
}
```

My service looks like:

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class VerificationService {

  private VerificationTokenRepository verificationTokenRepository;

  void removeUnusedVerificationTokens(LocalDateTime localDateTime) {
    verificationTokenRepository.deleteAllByCreatedLessThan(localDateTime.minusMinutes(30));
  }

}
```

After this short implementation, I want to test it like below:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class VerificationServiceTest {

  @InjectMocks
  private VerificationService verificationService;

  @Mock
  private VerificationTokenRepository tokenRepository;


  @BeforeEach
  void setUp() {
    verificationService = new VerificationService(tokenRepository);
  }

  @Test
  void removeUnusedVerificationTokens() {

    //given
    given(tokenRepository.findAll()).willReturn(verificationTokenDataStab());
    //when
    verificationService.removeUnusedVerificationTokens(LocalDateTime.now().minusMinutes(30));
    //then
    assertAll(() -> assertEquals(tokenRepository.findAll().size(), 3));

  }

  List<VerificationToken> verificationTokenDataStab() {
    return
        List
            .of(
                VerificationToken.builder().created(LocalDateTime.now().minusMinutes(65)).build(),
                VerificationToken.builder().created(LocalDateTime.now().minusMinutes(22)).build(),
                VerificationToken.builder().created(LocalDateTime.now().minusMinutes(200)).build(),
                VerificationToken.builder().created(LocalDateTime.now().minusMinutes(90)).build(),
                VerificationToken.builder().created(LocalDateTime.now().minusMinutes(10)).build(),
                VerificationToken.builder().created(LocalDateTime.now().minusMinutes(5)).build(),
                VerificationToken.builder().created(LocalDateTime.now().minusMinutes(35)).build());
  }
}
```

Problem is that in my assertion I am expecting size `3` after call method `removeUnusedVerificationTokens` but after all collection size is not changed and it is still `7`.

According to the documentation, method: 
`void deleteAll()` from CrudRepository

> Deletes all entities managed by the repository

So I am assuming that `deleteAll` should affect the entire collection but that not happened.

Seemingly method should work properly but after all, the test cannot confirm this. I will be grateful for the suggestions how to fix the above Spring Data query to reach a goal.

Comment: Could you try to replace deleteAllByCreatedLessThan with deleteByCreatedLessThan ? Also you should add in your properties file : spring.jpa.show-sql=true
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE To see the actual query

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems here (however there is no any problem with the query method itself):

1. You mock the `VerificationTokenRepository` then you pass this mock object to the constructor of the `VerificationService`. So when you call its `removeUnusedVerificationTokens` method it will call the mock object's underlaying method which does **absolutely nothing** by default.
2. You define a return value for the next call for `tokenRepository.findAll()` which returns a list of 7 objects, then you test the result of this call. Of course it returns a list of 7 objects, that's exactly what you defined 3 lines above.

I recomment you to read some articles about Mockito and how mocks and mocked methods are working.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you suggest a way how to test this particular method? Due to the fact that this method is void type I only can check if this method was called or there is a different chance to verify if the Spring Data method did what it suppose?

Comment: You can only test it via integration tests. Put some data into an in-memory DB duriung the test, call the method then check if the appropriate entries were deleted fromt he DB.